# Linebreaks in the names of subsections in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, line-breaking, books, subsection, overfull

I’m dealing with the following problem. The name of a subsection in my book is too long and it could not fit in the TOC. Could anyone suggest the solution to insert a line-break in TOK?

That is the part of my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{misccorr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[resetlabels,labeled]{multibib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Additions}
\section{The Applications of Induced Representations}
\subsection[Normal Divisors and Applications to Powers of \protect\linebreak Irreducible Representations]{Normal Divisors and Applications to Powers of Irreducible Representations}
%The problem is in this particular line 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Since `russian` is your last specified language with `babel` this is used for the document and its hyphenation rule. That means, LaTeX thinks `Irreducible` is a Russian word and apparently can't hyphenate it correctly. You either need to change the order or specify the language for the sections, i.e. `\subsection{\foreignlanguage{english}{Normal Divisors and Applications to Powers of Irreducible Representations}}`. (Quick fix would be `Irre\-ducible` but that's not a good idea in the long run.)

Comment: Obviously, if you use Russian text and more than one English header, I'd define a few macros like `\enSection` and `\enSubsection` so that you don't have to use `\foreignlanguage` manually anymore.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel thank you! that’s very helpful! could you also tell how to fix this problem if the default language is the same as the language of a subsection name?